# Get the span element using selenium, python

Tags: python, html, selenium, chromium

I want to get the span element i.e 3.000 in my case

This is the code

```
<span class="ps_box-value" aria-disabled="true" id="DERIVED_ACRD_FL_DESCR50$0">3.000</span>
```

I've tried the following

```
gpa= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DERIVED_ACRD_FL_DESCR50$0"]').getText()
```

and also

```
gpa= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DERIVED_ACRD_FL_DESCR50$0"]').getAttribute()
print("gpa", gpa)
```

It shows the error:

> AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'

How to extract 3.000? I have been stuck for quite a while, kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried so `gpa= self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('ps_box-value')`?

Comment: @gorevanova It returns <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3a58dccaf1f94b3e89e8b06a917dbf55", element="5c9e0bda-00bf-471e-af87-8ef7b2925317")>. There are other elements also in the 'ps_box-value' example the cumulative gpa

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe it is just .text, not getText()

Comment: Yes, it worked. It was .text. Thank you guys.